# highcharts exported image options

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using the following code to get png export:

```
    var added_chart_options = {
    credits:{
        enabled: true
    },
    title:{
        style:{
            display: 'block'
        }
    },
    subtitle:{
        style:{
            display: 'block'
        }
    }
};

var options = Highcharts.merge(false, Highcharts['charts'][0]['options'], added_chart_options);

var data = {
    options: JSON.stringify(options),
     resources: {
         css: ".highcharts-background { fill: #fff; stroke: #0ff; stroke-width: 2px}"
    },
    filename: 'test.png',
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
};

var exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/';
$.post(exportUrl, data, function(data) {
    var imageUrl = exportUrl + data;
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    fetch(imageUrl).then(response => response.blob()).then(data => {console.log(data, imageUrl)});
})
```

I have multiple problems:

1. How to set fonts for exported image? Currently I have added font using custom css to whole project.
2. legend defers from what I am seeing. it collapses texts (even in lines that is not needed)
3. formatter is not working. In xAxis dataLabels I have used a formatter and is not working in export.

*update1*

my legend code is:

```
 legend:{
        useHTML: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        layout: "horizontal",
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        alignColumns: true,
        rtl: true,
        itemWidth: null,
        x: 20
    },
```

and it is perfectly shown in browser, but after export it is exploded. The problem is that the width seems to be limited and even the legend's lines that are short enough to fill the width are collapsed.

Comment: **2.** Please provide a code necessary to recreate the legend of your chart.

Comment: @KamilKulig done

Answer (score 0):

**Live demo** for all 3 answers: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2ndyxm8/

> 1. How to set fonts for exported image? Currently I have added font using custom css to whole project.

`style.fontFamily` property  is used in Highcharts for specifying a font (applied to `dataLabels` in the demo). Default Highcharts exporting server supports many google fonts - I recommend to try it out and see if the desired font is supported.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'Cinzel' // Google font
  }
},
```

> 2. legend defers from what I am seeing. it collapses texts (even in lines
>      that is not needed)

I couldn't reproduce that. Please fork and edit the above demo so that it recreates the problem.

> 3. formatter is not working. In xAxis dataLabels I have used a formatter
>      and is not working in export.

Formatters don't work in exporting if you define them normally (as callback function) or as a String in `dataLabels.formatter` property. They work if you `update` the chart in `options.callback` String like this:

```
  callback: `function(chart) {
    chart.series[0].update({
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return 'Font and formatter test';
        }
      }
    });
  }`
```

Comment: thanks for your complete answer. for the font: I need to have custom font, is it possible?  for the legend I would do it soon in another comment. for the third one my formatter is about null values. The code you have written igonres null values totally. Is there any way to fix these two? tnx

Comment: **1. Fonts:** If your're using default Highcharts exporting server (export.highcharts.com), you can only use the fonts that are installed on it. If your font is not supported by the default export server you can try either **client side export** or **set up your own server**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export **2. Formatter:** The point has no value so Highcharts doesn't know where to put its data label and simply omits it. That sounds like a reasonable approach to me.